# Are marshmallows an effective remedy for sore throats?

Tags: home-remedies, medical-myths, sore-throat, gelatin

Over the weekend, I developed an intense sore throat, (it may well be strep throat -- results are pending). Anyway, I've been looking for any and all means to help ease the pain, and my boyfriend came across several articles indicating that marshmallows might help. One such articles is here: [14 Ways to Soothe a Sore Throat](http://www.health.com/health/gallery/0,,20640098,00.html)

> Although there's no hard evidence that it works, sap from the
> marshmallow plant has been used for hundreds of years—usually in tea
> form—to treat coughs, colds, and sore throats. And while real
> marshmallow bears little relation to the puffy campfire treats that
> took its name, both may have sore throat-fighting properties.
>
> According to anecdotal reports, modern-day marshmallows can help ease
> sore throat pain, possibly because the gelatin coats and soothes.
> "It's not the wackiest thing in the world," Dr. Linder says. "If your
> throat is really swollen and it really hurts to swallow anything, I
> can see how something slippery and sweet like marshmallows might
> provide some relief."

While it is clear that marshmallow roots would be much more effective than the sugary marshmallow puffs, **I was wondering if gelatin properties or if any properties left of a marshmallow puff are still helpful nevertheless? Or is it all a placebo?**

(I do not have marshmallows at my home and have not tested it personally).